# Какая разница между pow() и math.pow()?

Tags: python, функции, модули

Опишите подробно, какая разница между встроенной функцией pow() и функцией pow() из библиотеки math?

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow): «Unlike the built-in `**` operator, `math.pow()` converts both its arguments to type `float`. Use `**` or the built-in `pow()` function for computing exact integer powers.»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У встроенной функции `pow`, в отличие от `math.pow` есть необязательный аргумент `mod`.

С заданным аргументом `mod` результат вызова эквивалентен следующему коду:

```py
pow(base, exp) % mod
```

но вычисляется эффективнее.

Также `math.pow` работает с дробными числами, а `pow` - с целыми:

```py
>>> pow(2, 3)
8
>>> math.pow(2, 3)
8.0
```

Иногда это отличие может быть полезно.

Подробнее в документации [по встроенной функции `pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) и [по функции `math.pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow).

Comment: Какой тогда смысл в math.pow(), если результат ее работы можно получить с помощью кода float(pow(x, y))?

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответ )

Comment: @Max я добавил ещё одно отличие. PS: если вам помог этот ответ, примите его (серая галочка слева).

Comment: pow тоже умеет работать с флоатами, а ещё с комплексными числами: `pow(-2.5, -2.5)` возвращает результат, а `math.pow(-2.5, -2.5)` кидает ошибку "math domain error". В чём смысл существования math.pow тогда вообще?)

Comment: (разве что могу предположить, что, так как math.pow ограничен флоатами, он может работать немножко быстрее, но пруфов не видел и сам бенчмарки не делал)